# Sample Android NDK hello-gl2 unable to compile on Android Studio

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm able to run the hello-jni of the samples provided in the NDK but I can't compile the hello-gl2 sample.

Could you help me? (I think is a problem linking with OpenGL)

This are the errors reported by Android Studio:

```
C:\AndroidstudioProjects\hello-gl2\app\src\main\jni\gl_code.cpp
Error:(39) undefined reference to `glGetError'
Error:(41) undefined reference to `__android_log_print'
Error:(40) undefined reference to `glGetError'
Error:(34) undefined reference to `glGetString'
Error:(35) undefined reference to `__android_log_print'
Error:(58) undefined reference to `glCreateShader'
Error:(60) undefined reference to `glShaderSource'
Error:(61) undefined reference to `glCompileShader'
Error:(63) undefined reference to `glGetShaderiv'
Error:(66) undefined reference to `glGetShaderiv'
Error:(70) undefined reference to `glGetShaderInfoLog'
Error:(72) undefined reference to `__android_log_print'
Error:(75) undefined reference to `glDeleteShader'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Android.mk file (in the /jni folder), there should be a LOCAL_LDLIBS line. Some of the libraries that come bundled with Android need to be indicated here. Try the following

LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM

Or at least add the options -lEGL and -lGLESv1_CM.  The first is the EGL library, and the second is the GLES library.

I don't know if the last one is the right version number for your project though.

Comment: Unfortunately this don't work, but thank you for your help. I finally import the project on Eclipse and the project worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used eclipse (for those that are dealing with the same problems) and with Eclipse all went fine.